# need PHP function to echo a value when another is empty

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I have 2 inputs, one for username, and one for ID.

- Username value: `<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('username') ); ?>`
- ID value: `<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('id') ); ?>`

and a division:

```
<div id="info"><?php echo esc_attr( get_option('username') ); ?></div>
```

I want a PHP function to echo `<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('ID') ); ?>` in div#info ONLY IF the username field is not filled by the user.

Thank you.

P.S: Apologize if similar topics already exist, but I have looked'em up and couldn't find a straight answer for such a beginner.

Comment: `if(empty....){...} else{...}` or use a ternary operator which would work best.

Comment: Thanks! apply that to my code ;)

Comment: This isn't meant to sound rude but have you applied it to your code? @Fred-ii- provided everything you need to answer your question. However it's not his job or anyone else's to write your code for you.

Comment: You've got the *best of both worlds* below. Try 'em out ;-)

Comment: Thank you. just slow down with a beginner lol. Thanks Fred, your code worked, War10ck, will do :)

Comment: You're welcome, *cheers* - Ternary's one of the best thing since sliced bread ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need a function a simple `if` `else` will do your job

```
if(empty(get_option('username')) {
    echo '<div id="info">'. esc_attr( get_option('username') ) . '</div>';
} else {
echo esc_attr( get_option('username') );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, yiiframe !

Answer (score 2):

Can go for ternary

```
<div id="info"><?php echo (!empty(esc_attr( get_option('username') ))) ? esc_attr( get_option('username') ) : esc_attr( get_option('id') ); ?></div>
```